# swap 2 columns in a html table using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to write a Javascript function to swap the second column with the third column, we will open the console and write your function then call it to test.

[image: Third column (a3-b3-c3) needs to take place of (a2-b2-c2) after calling the function]

index.html

```
    <table style="margin:auto;" id="tabel1" class="mytabel" width="300" height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
        border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> A1 </td>
                <td> A2 </td>
                <td> A3 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> B1 </td>
                <td> B2 </td>
                <td> B3 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> C1 </td>
                <td> C2 </td>
                <td> C3 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

script.js ( so far )

```
function swap(){
    //Write your code here

    var tRows = document.getElementById('tabel1').children[0].children;

    var column2 = [];
    var column3 = [];


    for(var i = 0; i < tRows.length; i++) {
        column2[i] = tRows[i].children[1];
        column3[i] = tRows[i].children[2];
    }

    console.log("cell2 " , column2);
    console.log("cell3 " , column3);

}

swap();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this alone (no need for a function around it - just put this directly in the browser console):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#tabel1 tr').forEach(tr=>tr.append(tr.querySelectorAll('td')[1]))
```

This works by, for each row of the table, appending the second (index 1) td to the end of the row. When you append an element somewhere, it is removed from where it was.

```js
function swap(){
     document.querySelectorAll('#tabel1 tr')
         .forEach(tr=>tr.append(tr.querySelectorAll('td')[1]))
}
swap();
```

```html
<table style="margin:auto;" id="tabel1" class="mytabel" width="300" height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
       border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> A1 </td>
      <td> A2 </td>
      <td> A3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> B1 </td>
      <td> B2 </td>
      <td> B3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> C1 </td>
      <td> C2 </td>
      <td> C3 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, please update your answer to explain how this works and solves the question.

Comment: Much better :) Explaining the code makes the answer useful to other users with similar but not identical questions, as they can adapt the code to work in their situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over all the rows and use `.insertBefore` to switch their positions.

```
function swap(){
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#tabel1 > tbody > tr");
    for(const row of rows){
      row.insertBefore(row.children[2], row.children[1]);
    }
}
```

Demo:

```js
function swap(){
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#tabel1 > tbody > tr");
    for(const row of rows){
      row.insertBefore(row.children[2], row.children[1]);
    }
}
swap();
```

```html
<table style="margin:auto;" id="tabel1" class="mytabel" width="300" height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
       border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> A1 </td>
      <td> A2 </td>
      <td> A3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> B1 </td>
      <td> B2 </td>
      <td> B3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> C1 </td>
      <td> C2 </td>
      <td> C3 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be mindful that tables can have header and footer sections, as well as multiple tbodys.

Using *children[0].children* is a little too abstract, there are historic *rows* and *cells* collections that are easier to use and more semantic than selectors.

In the case of a single tbody, you can get the table's *rows*, then adjust each row's *cells*, e.g.:

```js
function swapCells() {
  Array.from(document.querySelector('#tabel1').rows).forEach(row => row.append(row.cells[1]));
}
```

```html
<table style="margin:auto;" id="tabel1" class="mytabel" width="300" height="100" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td> A1 </td><td> A2 </td><td> A3 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> B1 </td><td> B2 </td><td> B3 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> C1 </td><td> C2 </td><td> C3 </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="swapCells()">Swap rows</button>
```

PS The misspelling "tabel" is an additional challenge. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `childNodes` instead of `children` the following code will solve the issue:

```html
table.insertBefore(table.childNodes[1].childNodes[3], table.childNodes[2].childNodes[5])
```

Where table is the Table element, => childNodes[1] is the `<tbody>` (because of how nodes work. the 0th element is actually empty text) => childNodes[3] and [5]are the `<tr>`s (counting in the text nodes)